# TYPO3 6.2 Host migration : Slowness issue when displaying category tree in Backend

Tags: performance, migration, backend, categories, typo3-6.2.x

Basicaly, we have tons of category. And when I edit a plugin or a page, there is a category tree.
On the actual production, displaying this tree in backend take just few seconds.

But now, on migration server (which is supposed to be more powerful), its taking way way much more time to display this tree, like, 8 times longer. And i don't know why, cause settings are the same.

I tried many things, even updating index, (but, that didnt fix anything).

So, for me, its a server configuration issue, but i know nothing about that.

Can someone advice me, cause i dont know where to look now.

Thank you !

Comment: It would be helpful to share parts of your code where your struggling

Comment: Well, which part of code? cause its not inside an extension or anything, its just the basic flexform of any plugin or page with the category tree inside. Thank you, for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we found a solution to my problem! 
After working with sysadmin, we realized that the problem was our MySQL version. We were using a MySQL server version 5.6, and for some reason, typo3 didnt like it. So we set the server as our actual production: MariaDB 10.0.30, and we saw a huge improvment.
(Editing a plugin took something like 1.3 min with MySQL server, and now it takes 15 sec with MariaDB)

Maybe someone has explainations to this improvment?

(We are aware that having 1500 categories is a terrible idea, TYPO3 is not supposed to work like that, but thats not our decision, and we will manage to change/improve that in the future)